# "Too many connections" error in a PHPUnit using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I'm unit testing a Zend Framework based project with PHPUnit, it seems like there's too many tests.

**Symptoms** : I'm writing another test and launching this test on this specific function caused the test to fail with error

**Stacktrace** :

```
Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections in /Users/MyUser/workspaces/gitrepo/myprojectcom/webapp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144

Call Stack:
    0.0002     639184   1. {main}() /Users/MyUser/pear/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0036    1243552   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /Users/MyUser/pear/bin/phpunit:46
    0.0036    1244568   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:130
    0.0036    1244568   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:139
    0.0202    5745936   5. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:671
    0.0202    5747448   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuite() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Configuration.php:768
    0.0539    6143840   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Configuration.php:848
    0.8321   26889016   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:419
    0.8329   27067008   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestSuite() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:392
    0.8329   27068424  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->__construct() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:318
    0.8554   27706232  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestMethod() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:214
    0.8555   27706384  12. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::createTest() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:831
    0.8556   27719664  13. ControllerTestCaseAbstract->__construct() /Users/MyUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:554
    0.8586   27775696  14. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap() /Users/MyUser/workspaces/gitrepo/myprojectcom/webapp/tests/ControllerTestCaseAbstract.php:24
    0.8586   27775696  15. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap() /Users/MyUser/workspaces/gitrepo/myprojectcom/webapp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:586
    0.8586   27775696  16. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource() /Users/MyUser/workspaces/gitrepo/myprojectcom/webapp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:629
    0.8586   27776040  17. Bootstrap->_initDb() /Users/MyUser/workspaces/gitrepo/myprojectcom/webapp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:669
    0.8590   27782440  18. Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->getConnection() /Users/MyUser/workspaces/gitrepo/myprojectcom/webapp/application/Bootstrap.php:97
    0.8590   27782440  19. Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() /Users/MyUser/workspaces/gitrepo/myprojectcom/webapp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:315
    0.8591   27782440  20. Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() /Users/MyUser/workspaces/gitrepo/myprojectcom/webapp/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:109
```

To avoid doubt here's my database bootstrap function:

```
protected function _initDb() {
    $databaseConfig = $this->_getDbConfig(); //loaded from an .ini file
    $resource = Zend_Db::factory($databaseConfig);
    $resource->getConnection();
    Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($resource);
    return $resource;
}
```

**Various other elements** :

- Commenting one class's test method let me add a this new test case without problem, so the problem doesn't came from my specific new case, but from the amount of test done
- I have a very basic _initDb bootstrap function as you can see
- This fail also when launching the whole test suite without using "--filter"
- My environment is : Mac OS X 10.7.3 Lion, XAMPP's MySQL server 5.1.44, PHPunit 3.6.11 installed through PEAR, PHP 5.3.8
- I do close my connection in the tear down [EDIT]

**What I'm looking for** : any explanation and above all a workaround

**Workaround already found** : adding a dirty fix in the [mysqld] of /Applications/XAMPP/etc/my.cnf :

```
set-variable=max_connections=200
```

Comment: It's a functional or end-to-end test? Why you're not using Mock Object?

Comment: End-to-end I'm trying to test a whole stack.

Answer (score 1):

You should use closeConnection() from [Zend_Db_Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.closing).

When you write your web app, there is (usually) no need to explicitly close the connection, because your script starts, executes few queries and ends clearing out all opened connections. In case of your test, you most likely have some long running script, which opens many connections, but since script is not ended, those connections are not cleared out, so yu will have to close them explicitly when you don't need them.

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question but I've tried to had a tear down closing existing connection, that didn't change anything

Comment: Can you log and check if tear down is really executed? Also, how many connections do you open before tear down? It might happen that call to tear down is not "soon enough"...

Comment: How can I tell how many MySQL connections are open ? Shall I put a static counter ?

Comment: I put a static counter : teardown is called after all setup has been called. What can I do against it ?

Comment: I would try closing connections earlier than teardown. You have one test method, close connection in every particular test.

Comment: This problem occures even if I'm selecting one single test with the --filter option, using this filter no test is run but all instantiate, the problem will remain the same.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with phpunit, but you should run your tests one by one (not to initialize all of them at the same time)....or (if that is not possible), don't open your database connection on initialization, but inside the test. If that is not possible, too (thought I'm sure it is) then you really need many mysql connections opened at the same time, so there is nothing wrong to increase max_connections.

Comment: I'm not specifically asking PHPunit to behave like that, and putting initialization out of the setup() method is counter-intuitive (I mean the setup exist for that given purpose. Nevertheless I do appreciate all the help you're trying to provide.